# Python. Optimize Append DF to MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I am adding in a DB the output of a model like this:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for i in range(len(df)):
    UserId = df.loc[i, 'UserId']
    Timestamp = df.loc[i, 'Timestamp']
    ChurnPropensity = df.loc[i, 'ChurnPropensity']

    sql = "INSERT INTO DB_Name (UserId, Timestamp, ChurnPropensity) VALUES ({},'{}',{});".format(UserId, Timestamp, ChurnPropensity)

    cursor.execute(sql)

conn.commit()
```

However, it takes a long time due to the for loop. How would you improve computation time?

Salut,

Comment: How big is the table? Have you tried using `pd.DataFrame.to_sql`?

Comment: I have actually, but did not manage to set up properly the 'create_engine' bit.

The table is a few thousand rows, but I'd like it to be able to easily scale.

Comment: Managed to get `pd.DataFrame.to_sql` working, and time was reduced by 90% :)

Comment: Awesome. But I think there are still bottlenecks with bulk inserts even with `to_sql` because of the I/O. You can try building raw queries and then using sqlalchemy to execute them as well. But great it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method. Ideally it should speed up the execution.

```
query = "INSERT INTO DB_Name (UserId, Timestamp, ChurnPropensity) VALUES ({},'{}',{});"
df.apply(lambda row: cursor.execute(query.format(row['UserId'], 
                                                 row['Timestamp'], 
                                                 row['ChurnPropensity'])),
axis=1)
```

From my experience, `execute` method itself is slow, so you could speed up by 
 trying to execute multiple queries at once.

```
query = "INSERT INTO DB_Name (UserId, Timestamp, ChurnPropensity) VALUES ({},'{}',{});"
queries_list = df.apply(lambda row: query.format(row['UserId'], 
                                            row['Timestamp'], 
                                            row['ChurnPropensity']),  axis=1).values.tolist()

queries = ' '.join(queries_list)
cursor.execute(queries, multi=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! but it takes the same amount of time.

Comment: unexpected keyword argument 'multi'